# How to prevent Slick from updating the primary key column?

Tags: scala, slick

I'm writing a dao for updating a model user; here is the code:

```
  case class User(id: Option[String] = None, username: String, password: String)


  object Users extends Table[User]("user") {

    // .... some column defines

    def * = id.? ~ username ~ password <>(User, User.unapply _)


    def byId(id: String) = Query(Users).filter(_.id === id)

    // user.id will be None since id is passed as parameter.
    def update(id: String, user: User)(implicit session: Session) = {
      byId(id).update(user)
      getById(id)
    }
```

I got this error :

```
[error]     JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "id"; SQL statement:
[error] update "user" set "id" = ?, "username" = ?, "password" = ? where "user".
"id" = 'RBq0kJAs' [23502-168] (DbException.java:169)
```

It seems Slick generates a SQL statement which updates the primary column "id", which has no point.
How can the id column be removed from the generated update query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Slick Documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0/lifted-embedding.html#updating):

> Updates are performed by writing a query that selects the data to update and then replacing it with new data.

So since your query selects the `id`, the update statements attempts to replace it. – You may want to check out the example in the documentation (see link above).

Comment: adding newer documentation link (for slick 3.2) http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/queries.html#updating

Answer (score 0):

Running on Postgres SQL (tested on v9.5), you can used the `insertOrUpdate` Slick call.

```
// Assuming table query is property `users`
private val users = TableQuery[UsersTable]

def update(id: String, user: User)(implicit session: Session):Future[User] =
    for {
        _ ← db.run(users.insertOrUpdate(user))
        readBack ← getById(id) // Existing query against `users`
    } yield readBack
```